# Excel VBA - When 2 cells in a column are the same, add the 2 corrisponce number in the next column

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I have three columns in my spreadsheet ID, Time and Height. What I want to do is run through the ID column and where the IDs match (Same ID occurs more than once in the list) sum the Height together for the earliest time (see example 2)

Example 1 (What I currently have)

```
ID          Time    Height
AB123       06:00   10
AD1234      10:00   10
AC12345     14:00   10
AC12345     06:00   10
AE123456    10:00   10
```

Example 2 (What I'm looking for)

```
ID          Time    Height
AB123       06:00   10
AD1234      10:00   10
AC12345     14:00   10
AC12345     06:00   20
AE123456    10:00   10
```

Within the sheet there may be 2, 2, 3 or 4 occurrence of the same ID number with multiple times.

I someone could help me with the VBA code for this I'd be very grateful.

Comment: It could be done with the following formula in an empty column: `=IF(B2=MIN(IF($A$2:$A$6=A2,$B$2:$B$6)),SUMIF($A$2:$A$6,A2,$C$2:$C$6),C2)`

Comment: Thanks Scott. unfortunately I'm looking for VBA solution.

Comment: Then what have you tried?  Stack Overflow is not a code for me site.  Please post any attempt to do this on your own and specify the location of the error in the code so we may help with the specific problem in the existing code.